# How to call a composable function in a template in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have created a composable with a function for handling errors and a template for displaying the error:

**useErrorHandling.js**

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function useErrorHandling() {
  const errors = ref(null);

  function errorFor(field) {
    return errors.value && errors.value[field]
      ? errors.value[field]
      : null;
  }

  return {
    errors,
    errorFor,
  };
}
```

**ValidationErrors.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span
      v-for="(error, index) in props.errors"
      :key="key(index)"
    >
      {{ error }}
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['errors']);

const key = (index) => {
  return `validation_error_${index}_${Math.random()}`;
}
</script>
```

I am testing this on my login form, and in Vue Dev Tools when I check the errors value in Login form is being updated but it is not being sent to the `ValidationErrors` component.

**Login.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <div>
          <input
              v-model="formData.email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
        </div>
        <validation-errors :errors="errorFor('email')"></validation-errors>
      </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import useErrorHandling from '../../Shared/Composable/useErrorHandling.js';
import ValidationErrors from '../../Components/Form/ValidationErrors.vue';

let { errors, errorFor } = useErrorHandling();

const formData = reactive({
  email: "",
  password: ""
});

const login = async () => {
  axios
    .post('/api/auth/login', {
      email: formData.email,
      password: formData.password
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // Login user
    })
    .catch(error => {
      errors = error.response.data.errors;
    })
}
</script>
```

My question is, how can I call the `errorFor` function from my `Login.vue` form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errors` is a `ref()`, and you should update its value not the `ref()` itself, because you are replacing it with a non-reactive object.

```
const login = async () => {    
  axios
    .post("/api/auth/login", {
        email: formData.email,
        password: formData.password
    })
    .then((response) => {
        // Login user
    })
    .catch(error => {
        errors.value = error.response.data.errors;
    })
}
```

Also, as a side note, just a syntax suggestion, the `errorFor` function can be simplified to:

```
function errorFor(field) {
    return errors.value?.[field] ?? [];
}
```

Comment: Your version of `errorFor` returns `false` on failure, instead of `null`. It should instead be simply `(errors.value && errors.value[field]) ?? null`. You can use `||` if you can't use `??`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes You're right. On second thought, given that the value is used only in a for loop it makes more sense to return an [] in case of failure. Adding more syntax sugar it can be rewritten as: `errors.value?.[field] ?? []`